# What is .ptl format?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

I cannot find any PyTorch documentation describing .ptl format. The person posting [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-convert-pt-file-into-ptl-unsupportednodeerror-generatorexp-arent-supported/148797) calls it PyTorch Lite, which I assume refers to [this project](https://github.com/cedrickchee/pytorch-lite), but I see no mention of .ptl format there so I cannot tell if it is related at all. I have seen .ptl models in the wild, but there is mysteriously little information available about the format.

Answer (score 0):

`.ptl` refers to PyTorch models that target [the lite interpreter](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/mobile_interpreter.html) (mobile) on Android and iOS. Keep in mind that Pytorch Mobile is still in beta stage so those APIs *may* change until stable.

Comment: Even this just seems like a recipe with some snippets which refer to files ending in .ptl - is .ptl as a format documented anywhere?